# Обновить значение QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, mac, qlineedit

Всем добрый день!

Возник вопрос при разработке QT приложения. Ситуация такая: есть несколько QLineEdit. По нажатии одной кнопки все значения этих QLineEdit переносятся в глобальный QList:

```
    userList.append(ui->lineEdit->text());
    userList.append(ui->lineEdit_2->text());
    userList.append(ui->lineEdit_3->text());
    userList.append(ui->lineEdit_4->text());
```

Есть также и другая кнопка, при нажатии на которую значения из QList возвращаются в соответствующие им QLineEdit:

```
    ui->lineEdit->setText(userList[0]);
    ui->lineEdit_2->setText(userList[1]);
    ui->lineEdit_3->setText(userList[2]);
    ui->lineEdit_4->setText(userList[3]);
```

И действительно, кнопка работает, и значения переносятся, но их становится видно только после нажатия на QLineEdit. 
Вот пример:

До нажатия на QLineEdit-ы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на каждый из QLineEdit-ы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите, пожалуйста, это глюк версии IDE, в которой я работаю, или кодом значения QLineEdit нужно как-то обновлять? На "7" в третьей строчке не обращайте внимания, это setInputMask для ввода номера телефона.

Comment: Глюки, но попробуйте после вставки всех значений вызвать метод update у виджета на котором лежат все ваши lineedit

Comment: @AlexanderChernin update()  , увы, не помог( Всё то же самое